# Google Map GetLocation Return String

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this piece of code ,

```
geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
var state;

function addAddressToMap(response) {
  if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
    alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode that address");
  } 
  else {
    place = response.Placemark[0];
    state = place.AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.AdministrativeAreaName;
  }
}

// showLocation() is called when you click on the Search button
// in the form.  It geocodes the address entered into the form
// and adds a marker to the map at that location.
function showLocation() {
  var address = "mutiara damansara";
  geocoder.getLocations(address, addAddressToMap);

  return state;
}
```

Alright , updated the codes . I try to instantiate `showLocation()` , but the variable `state` isn't being updated by `addAddressToMap` function .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated code helps see the picture a little better.

It looks like `addAddressToMap()` is expecting a response variable from the function arguments.

When it's called by `geocoder.getLocations(address,addAddressToMap)` there's no response passed.

So, the first `if` statement `!response` is true, and `state` remains unset.

To fix, you need to pass something when you call `addAddressToMap()`.  It looks like that something is an `XMLHttpRequest` (Ajax) object from somewhere else in the script.

Comment: the thing is , I can't just return state from addAddressToMap function , because I have to pass the function inside the geocoder as an object only then at that instance , there's response .